# How do i convert 30 categories into numbers for scikit

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, python, scipy

I am new to statistics, Python, machine learning and Scikit-learn. However, I am trying this project where I have a CSV with 35 columns of student data. The first column is an ID which I think I can ignore. The last 3 columns are the grade 1, grade 2 and grade 3 scores. I have 400 rows. I want to see if I can learn some machine learning with it, and make some sense of the data I have. Now I understand Scikit works on Numpy arrays which do not handle categorical data like sex ('male', 'female') and so on. So I codified all the 30 categories with 1 for male, 2 for female and so on and so forth. I then did the following

```
X = my_data[:,1:33]
y = my_data[:,34]
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X,y)
expected = y
predicted = model.predict(X)
mse = np.mean((predicted-expected)**2)
print(mse)
print(model.score(X,y))
```

I got a MSE of 6.0839840461 and a model score of 0.709407474898.

I got some result. So far so good for a first attempt. However, I realized that since I assigned increasing code values like 1 for male, 2 for female, the Linear Regression would have treated them as weights. How do I replace the Gender column with [1,0] or [0,1], which I learn is the right way to represent categorical data? Would it be a dictionary type column or a list type column? If so how will it be part of the Numpy array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called **indicator** or **dummy variables**, and Pandas allows to easily encode such categorical values:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.get_dummies(['male', 'female'])
   female  male
0       0     1
1       1     0
```

Don't forget about [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity), though - algorithms like linear regression rely on independence of variables, while in your case `female=0` definitely means `male=1`. In this case simply remove one dummy variable (e.g. use only `female` var and not `male`).

Comment: This gives an example of get_dummies http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/logistic-regression-and-python.html

Answer (score 3):

There is also a LabelEncoder() in sklearn.preprocessing package:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

le1 = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y = le1.transform(y)
```

You can also inverse transform back with le1.inverse_transform(y).
The encoding is done automatically though, you cannot change the order.